# Why does this python function return a list of duplicates?

Tags: python, list, geolocation, iteration, repeat

I am trying to write a block of code which acts on two sets of geographic coordinates (in this case, neighbourhoods and violent crimes). It counts the number of crimes within a 500m radius of each neighbourhood, adds those numbers to a list, and then merges that list with the neighbourhood dataset.

```
#For each neighbourhood in city find all crimes committed within a 500m radius

from geopy import distance

def Crime_in_Hood(crimes):
#counts number of crimes in 500m radius of neighbourhood
   crime_count = 0
   
   for index, crime in crimes.iterrows():
       test_point = [{crime['Latitude'], crime['Longitude']}]
       radius = 0.5# in km

       center_point_tuple = tuple(center_point)
       test_point_tuple = tuple(test_point)

       dis = distance.distance(center_point_tuple, test_point_tuple).km

       if dis <= radius:
           crime_count = crime_count + 1
           
   return crime_count


def Crime_in_City(crimes, hoods):
#returns number of crimes for each neighbourhood in city
   
#instantiate crime tally
   violent_crimes = []
   
   for index, hood in hoods.iterrows():
       center_point = [{hood['Latitude'], hood['Longitude']}]
       crime_count = Crime_in_Hood(crimes, hoods)
       violent_crimes.append(crime_count)
       
   return violent_crimes

       
def Crime_Counter(crimes, hoods):

#Add the number of crimes committed to dataframe for each neighbourhood in city
   violent_crimes = Crime_in_City(crimes, hoods)

   #Add violent_crimes to hoods
   hoods["Violent Crimes"] = violent_crimes
   return hoods 


ny_hoods = Crime_Counter(ny_c, ny_hoods)
ny_hoods.head()
```

The problem is that it returns a dataframe where each value in the column "Violent Crimes is the same.

I tested the Crime_in_Hood function with different values and it works as expect. Crime_in_City, however, returns a list with the last crime_count value repeated over and over again. So I now that's where my problem is, just not how to fix it. As far as I can tell Crime_in_Hood should be returning a different value for every iteration of Crime_in_City and appending it to violent_crimes, but it's not.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the initial values for `ny_c` and `ny_hoods`? Do you have sample data?

Comment: They are both rather large dataframes. 

ny_c.dtype is as follows
 Date         datetime64[ns]
Charge               object
Latitude            float64
Longitude           float64

Comment: n_crimes.dtypes is:
Neighbourhood      object
Latitude          float64
Longitude         float64
dtype: object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crime_in_Hood(crimes) only has one defined parameter but you call it with 2 parameters here: crime_count = Crime_in_Hood(crimes, hoods). This is how your code should look (below). ny_c and ny_hoods should both be pandas DataFrames with 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' columns with float64 values. Other than that I am not sure about how geopy works in regards to: {Latitude, Longitude} notation.

```
#For each neighbourhood in city find all crimes committed within a 500m radius

from geopy import distance

def Crime_in_Hood(crimes, center_point):
#counts number of crimes in 500m radius of neighbourhood
   crime_count = 0
   
   for index, crime in crimes.iterrows():
       test_point = [{crime['Latitude'], crime['Longitude']}]
       radius = 0.5# in km

       center_point_tuple = tuple(center_point)
       test_point_tuple = tuple(test_point)

       dis = distance.distance(center_point_tuple, test_point_tuple).km

       if dis <= radius:
           crime_count = crime_count + 1
           
   return crime_count


def Crime_in_City(crimes, hoods):
#returns number of crimes for each neighbourhood in city
   
#instantiate crime tally
   violent_crimes = []
   
   for index, hood in hoods.iterrows():
       center_point = [{hood['Latitude'], hood['Longitude']}]
       crime_count = Crime_in_Hood(crimes, center_point)
       violent_crimes.append(crime_count)
       
   return violent_crimes


def Crime_Counter(crimes, hoods):

#Add the number of crimes committed to dataframe for each neighbourhood in city
   violent_crimes = Crime_in_City(crimes, hoods)

   #Add violent_crimes to hoods
   hoods["Violent Crimes"] = violent_crimes
   return hoods 


ny_hoods = Crime_Counter(ny_c, ny_hoods)
ny_hoods.head()
```

Comment: This looks like it worked in my tests. I'll let you know after it has crunched through all of the data. Thanks. ^_^